# Postgres SELECT rows where JSON array contains "most" of values

Tags: postgresql, json

I have the following table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    labels json
);

INSERT INTO items (labels) VALUES
('{"labels":[{"value":"apple","score":0.95},{"value":"fruit","score":0.94},{"value":"red","score":0.93}]}'),
('{"labels":[{"value":"apple","score":0.92},{"value":"fruit","score":0.92},{"value":"green","score":0.93}]}'),
('{"labels":[{"value":"orange","score":0.92},{"value":"fruit","score":0.92},{"value":"orange","score":0.90}]}'),
('{"labels":[{"value":"tomato","score":0.98},{"value":"vegetable","score":0.96},{"value":"red","score":0.95}]}'),
('{"labels":[{"value":"carrot","score":0.94},{"value":"vegetable","score":0.93},{"value":"orange","score":0.92}]}')
('{"labels":[{"value":"peach","score":0.92},{"value":"fruit","score":0.92},{"value":"yellow","score":0.91}]}')
```

I'm trying to find a way to query this table by the labels column, using the "intersection" criteria with a factor of similarity >= 2.

e.g. if I set `["peach", "fruit", "orange"]` array as the WHERE clause input, then the result should be:

```
 id|
---+
 3 |
---+
 6 |
---+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` combined with `json_array_elements`

```
select id from items where exists 
    (select 1 from json_array_elements(labels->'labels') f(x) 
        where x->>'value' in ('peach', 'fruit', 'orange') 
        having count(*)>=2
    );
```

It gives the answer you want, but good luck making it fast if the table is large.  (Changing from JSON to JSONB might speed it up slightly)